# Поместить картинки в div

Tags: html, css

нужно из этого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сделать вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.with-icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icons-for-third-part {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  background-color: #81868e;
}

.icons-for-third-part img {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="with-icons">
  <div class="icons-for-third-part"><img src="res/images/icon1-for-third-part.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="icons-for-third-part"><img src="res/images/icon2-for-third-part.png" alt=""></div>
  <div class="icons-for-third-part"><img src="res/images/icon3-for-third-part.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

подскажите пожалуйста как

Answer (score 0):

Варианты из комментариев под вопросом:

```
.with-icons { 
    display: flex; 
    justify-content: space-around; 
    width: 20%; 
    background-color: #BDBDBD; 
}
```

```
div.icons-for-third-part{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;
}
```